# Non Null values in Marklogic - Search JSON documents with attributes in array with not null values in Marklogic

Tags: javascript, marklogic, marklogic-8, marklogic-7

Structure of JSON documents required to be searched in Marklogic

```
{  
   "MESSAGEID":"18878285",
   "ORDERNUMBER":["2295796"],
   "CATEGORY":"F3702200000"
}
```

I wanted to search the URIs of all JSON documents in Marklogic that comprised of not null `ORDERNUMBER` using Javascript

I am using the following query but it is still showing the URIs for the documents comprising of `"ORDERNUMBER":[]`

```
cts.uris("",null,cts.andQuery
    ([
        cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("ORDERNUMBER", "*", "wildcarded"),
        cts.notQuery(cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("ORDERNUMBER",""))
    ])
);
```

Answer (score 4):

You normally have a few options, but the empty array case is particularly hard to distinguish. This is because it is neither an empty string value, nor a null, yet the property is truly present.

`cts.jsonPropertyScopeQuery("ORDERNUMBER", cts.trueQuery())` will match any doc that has that property.

`cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("ORDERNUMBER", "")` matches `ORDERNUMBER: ""` and `ORDERNUMBER: [""]`.

`cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("ORDERNUMBER", null)` matches `ORDERNUMBER: null`.

`cts.jsonPropertyValueQuery("ORDERNUMBER", "?*", "wildcarded")` matches `ORDERNUMBER: null` (not sure why), `ORDERNUMBER: "xx"`, and `ORDERNUMBER: ["xx"]`, but only if you enable filtering (which requires `cts.search`), or if you are able to find the appropriate wildcard settings.

To be honest, the simplest solution to my opinion is to just put a range index on `ORDERNUMBER`, and use a rangeQuery:

```
cts.rangeQuery(cts.pathReference('ORDERNUMBER'), '>', '')
```

HTH!